# Get greater number in a field? Alloy model checker

Tags: alloy

I want to return the greater number `max(loc.x)` in a field scope:

```
sig Locations{
 x: set Int           // all x locations visited
 xgreater: one Int    // greater location
}

fact{all loc:Locations| xgreater = greaterX[loc]} // get greater location


fun greaterX[loc:Locations]:Int{     // get the greater location
 max(loc.x)                          // HOW do I do this?
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about making it a predicate

`pred greatest [locs: set Location, x: Location] {...}`

with a constraint that there is no location in lock larger than the x?

(Note also that I've changed the signature name to `Location`: as with classes and types, the convention is to use the singular noun.)

Comment: It did solve my problem indirectly! I don't even need to get the greater number, I just need to constraint the "x" in my Locations' set. Thank you! ```fact{no x:Location | x>10 }``` (where 10 is my maximum x allowed).     PS. Although to get the largest number in a set, I assume you can use the fact that Int is an ordered list, but I am not sure how. Regards!